# Error 403: You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: heroku, web-deployment, composer-php

Deployed my web app to Heroku, no errors. However when I got to open the app, it says 403 You don't have permission to access / on this server.

I have already looked into the spelling of "Procfile" and I tried using the code provided on another forum but it springs an error when I try to deploy it.

```
      "php artisan clear-compiled",
      "php artisan optimize",
      "chmod -R 777 AAS/public/"
    ]
```

This is the error that shows in the server logs.

```
 2019-05-07T15:41:17.899066+00:00 app[web.1]: [Tue May 07 15:41:17.895803 2019] [autoindex:error] [pid 138:tid 140579161761536] [client 10.11.89.47:16532] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /app/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive, referer: https://dashboard.heroku.com/
```

I understand this is due to trying to access the app folder instead of public folder but I have no clue how to correct that.

I hope the server accesses the public folder, and displays the web app correctly.

All advice is welcome. 
Thanks in advance. 
-Michael

Comment: Is your index.php file located on root level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are deploying php file then you need to keep php file in folder like `web` and your Procfile should look like `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 web/`